# Bash - error code in if statement not working

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, error-code

I am writing a bash script which does a backup to a mounted drive.

The backup itself works fine however even if there is an error during transfer it will say its successful.

```
backup() {
echo -e "Backup Started\n" >> $1
echo -e "Mounting backup Drive" >> $1
mount $2 /mnt 2>>$1
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
   echo -e "Backup Drive: $2 mounted successfully" >> $1
   cd /
   echo -e "Sync data to $2\n" >> $1
   nice -n 19 rsync -lHa --exclude-from '/opt/ts/bin/exclude.txt' / /mnt/ 2> ${ERROR}
   local RETURNCODE=$?
   if [ $RETURNCODE -eq 23 ] ; then backup_failed "Backup Warning: Some files did not copy" $1 $2; fi
   if [ $RETURNCODE -eq 20 ] ; then backup_failed "Backup Failed: Transfer was terminated prematurely" $1 $2; fi
   if [ $RETURNCODE -eq 11 ] ; then backup_failed "Backup Failed: Input/Output Error [URGENT]" $1 $2; fi
   if [ $RETURNCODE -ne 0 ] ; then backup_failed "Backup Failed: Error while copying data" $1 $2; fi
   echo -e "Backup completed Successfully with code $RETURNCODE `date`\n" >> $1
   echo -e >> $1
   printf "Time taken: "%dh:%dm:%ds"\n" $(($SECONDS/3600)) $(($SECONDS%3600/60)) $(($SECONDS%60)) >> $1
   echo -e "##############################\n" >> $1
   mkdir -p /mnt/mnt /mnt/proc /mnt/tmp /mnt/lost+found
   cp -a /proc/mounts /proc/filesystems /mnt/proc
   umount $2
fi
}
```

Despite $RETURNCODE giving a value of 20 it does not trigger. Output is below.

Mounting backup Drive
Backup Drive: /dev/hda4 mounted successfully
Sync data to /dev/hda4

Backup completed Successfully with code 20 Sun May  4 11:04:48 EST 2014

Time taken: 0h:0m:3s

#

If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated :)

Comment: `set -x` is your friend. Trace the script's execution and see what it's actually doing.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend running this through http://shellcheck.net/ -- it has a lot of minor bugs that probably aren't responsible for your question, but still ought to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the function backup_failed is behaving as expected?

Also note that backup_failed will be triggered twice when RETURNCODE is not 0 and backup_failed doesn't terminate the script:

```
if [ $RETURNCODE -eq 20 ] ; then backup_failed ...
...
if [ $RETURNCODE -ne 0 ] ; then backup_failed ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks threadp :) You were right, backup_failed was not behaving as expected. There was an if statement which compared files that did not backup to a list of exclusions. This was from an older version of the script and was never going to trigger in the current one.

Comment: Actually, it's even worse than this, because if RETURNCODE is 20, it'll call `backup_failed` twice (as described), and also print "Backup completed Successfully with code 20 ..."

Comment: backup_failed terminates the script once it has completed, it is working as expected however I do plan to improve the code (I didn't make the script originally, I was asked to add some error handling and change from cpio to rsync) :)

Comment: Done, don't recall seeing the tick button there previously as I was looking for something to do just that. Thanks :)